# Why ActionBar not display my custom color?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

```
<style name="Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">    
    <item name="android:background">#AF0814</item>
    <item name="background">#AF0814</item>
</style>
```

This is my custom style.xml ,I want to change the background of the ActionBar.It works well in my Virtual Divice One(platform:2.2 API level:8).But not display my custom color in Virtual Device Two(platform:4.4 API level:19)

Virtual Device One：

[image: Virtual Device One]

Virtual Device Two:

[image]

Comment: Did you also modify the values-v11 and values-v14 files ?

Comment: if you didn't create those files create it and define the styles there again.

Comment: @user2247689 not work as well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a line

```
<style name="Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBar</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove follwoing line and see

```
<item name="background">#AF0814</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also copy paste the same code in styles.xml files of values-v11 and values-v14 folders

```
<style name="Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.MyActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">    
    <item name="android:background">#AF0814</item>
    <item name="background">#AF0814</item>
</style>
```

hope this helps

Comment: And when I modify other attribute such as android:paddingBottom of the styles.xml in values-v14,it works.

Comment: @cruelcage which type of AVDs you are testing on?